# Child table status

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table A with `ID`, `houseId` and `Task`. I have another table B with `ID`, `TbleAId`, `Description` and `Status`.

[image: Table Structure]

I want to get count of all the tasks, completed tasks (where the status for all is set to 'Completed') and incomplete tasks (where the status for all is not set to 'Completed')

Check out the image for a sample:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried a join and a group by.. but did not work

Comment: To me, the table structure does not make good sense.  Why is the houseid in TableA and not TableB?  I can see having a reference table for tasks, so "Paint" would be the task and could be applied to many tables.  I don't see having two tables at the task/houseid combination level.  What is generating the two tables?

Comment: The way i *understand* this question: `ID` in A is id of a *task*, `ID` in B is id of a sub-task, and `TableAID` is reference from sub-task to its parent task. If that assumption is correct, then i think the question was about counting all **tasks** that have all **sub-tasks** completed...

Comment: TblqAID is the ID for Table A

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have completely misread the question originally.  Thank you @poncha for clarifying it.  You want to summarize by task before summarizing by house:

```
select HouseId,
       count(*) as NumTasks,
       sum(case when NotCompletedSubTask = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Completed,
       sum(case when NotCompletedSubtask > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NotCompleted
from (select b.TbleAId, a.HouseId
             sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as CompletedSubTask,
             sum(case when status <> 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as NotCompletedSubTask
      from TableB b join
           TableA a
           on b.TbleAID = a.ID
      group by b.TbleAId, a.HouseId
     ) t
group by HouseId
```

Comment: TableAID is task id, not house id (as far as i understand the sample data)

Comment: Thanks . . . I fixed the query.  The table structure really is a mess.

Comment: I'm not sure this will produce the expected results... see, it will count the total number of sub-tasks from B that are completed or not, but will not summarize whether or not **all** the subtasks of the same task are completed... well, at least that is what i think the OP wanted

Answer (score 0):

The way i *understand* this question: `A.ID` is id of a *task*, `B.ID` is id of a *sub-task*, and `B.TableAID` is reference from sub-task to its parent task.

If that assumption is correct, then i think the question was about counting all **tasks** that have all **sub-tasks** completed...

Kinda complicated, but more or less it should look like this, unless you're going to use temporary tables or code outside SQL:

```
SELECT
A.HouseID,
COUNT(DISTINCT A.ID) as `Total Task`,
SUM(IF(C.TableAID IS NOT NULL AND C.total=C.completed,1,0)) AS `Completed Tasks`,
SUM(IF(C.TableAID IS NOT NULL AND C.total=C.completed,0,1)) AS `Incomplete Tasks`
FROM A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT TableAID,COUNT(*) AS total, SUM(IF(status='Completed',1,0)) AS completed
  FROM B
  GROUP BY TableAID
  ) AS C ON A.ID=C.TableAID
GROUP BY A.HouseID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  HouseID,
  count(*) as Total_Tasks,
  Sum(Total_SubTask=Completed_SubTask) as Completed_Tasks,
  Sum(Total_SubTask<>Completed_SubTask) as Incomplete_Tasks
FROM
  TableA inner join (
    SELECT
      TbleAID,
      Count(*) as Total_SubTask,
      Sum(Status='Completed') as Completed_SubTask
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY TbleAID) s on tablea.ID = s.TbleAID
GROUP BY HouseID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another double grouping solution, which uses a slightly different method:

```
SELECT
  a.HouseID,
  COUNT(*)                        AS TotalTasks,
  COUNT(b.TaskStatus = 1 OR NULL) AS CompletedTasks,
  COUNT(b.TaskStatus < 1 OR NULL) AS InCompleteTasks
FROM TableA a
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      TbleAID,
      AVG(CASE Status WHEN 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TaskStatus
    FROM TableB
    GROUP BY TbleAID
  ) b ON a.ID = b.TbleAID
GROUP BY a.HouseID
;
```

Basically, it replaces text statuses with numerical ones: 1 for `Completed` and 0 for the other(s). For every task, the average status is calculated. If it turns out to be 1, it means all the subtasks are also 1, i.e. completed, so the task is completed too.

If at least one subtask is not completed, the average will be less than 1, thus indicating that the whole task is incomplete.

You can try this solution [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ae05/1).